# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] error

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am currently trying to insert data from a CSV file into my mysql data base.  The form and all the functions work properly because I've tested to make sure It's reading file, etc.  When I prepare the PDO to insert into mysql I get no error in Chrome.  Now when I let it `execute()` that's when I get server error in Chrome(any browser) and I looked in my error log file that showed up where function is saying:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] 
   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I'll paste my code on the function that I have made.
Code:

```
function returnBack(){

    header("Location:csvuploader/csvuploaderform.php?seterror=1");
    exit;

}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    /*******************************CHECK TO MAKE SURE FORM IS PROPERLY FILLED AND GET NAME OF COLUMNS IN CSV FILE *********************************************************/
    if (empty($_FILES['file'] ) )
    {
        returnBack();

    } 
    if (empty($_POST['firstname'])){
        echo "firstname is empty";

        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['lastname'])){
        echo "lastname is empty";

        returnBack();
    }if (empty($_POST['email'])){
        echo "email is empty";

        returnBack();
    }
    if (empty($_POST['phone'])){

        returnBack();
    }

    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];    

    $handle = fopen($file , "r");

    $fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",");

    $fileop=array_map("strtoupper",array_map("trim",$fileop));

    $firstname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST["firstname"]),$fileop);
    if ($firstname_index===false){
        returnBack();
    }
    $lastname_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['lastname']),$fileop);
    if ($lastname_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    $email_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['email']),$fileop);
    if ($email_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    $phone_index = array_search(strtoupper($_POST['phone']),$fileop);
    if ($phone_index===false){

        returnBack();
    }
    /***********************ASSIGN COLUMN VALUES TO ACCORDING VARIABLES AND INSERT THEM INTO CSV TABLE IN DB *************************************/
    try {  
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);  
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo "I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't do that.";  
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);   
    }
    /*$fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")*/
    while (($fileop=fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
    {

        $fileop=array_map("trim",$fileop);

        $firstname = $fileop[$firstname_index];

        $lastname = $fileop[$lastname_index];

        $email = $fileop[$email_index];

        $phone = $fileop[$phone_index];


        $insertdata = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csvdata (firstname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$phone')");
        //var_dump($insertdata);

        $insertdata->execute();


    }

}


$DBH = null;
```

UPDATED ------------------------------------- Heres some info

PHP info - `PHP Version 5.3.10, System  Windows NT W03 6.0 build 6002 (Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2) i586`

UPDATED ------------------------------------

I am able to connect to MySQL server and browse it - insert data from other functions that I have made and they all work perfect. It is just this one will give me an error.

UPDATED -------------------------------------------------------------------------

Figured it out guys thanks for all your help.  I actually needed to fill in all the data columns for it to work.  For instance I had (firstname,lastname,email,phone) I needed to fill in the username,password,status part.  Thanks for all your help guys!  Hope this will help anyone who falls in the same hole!

Comment: maybe your username and or password are incorrect

Comment: @Ibu No, "machine actively refused it" implies a firewall issue or server not listening on TCP.

Comment: @Michael do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @DavidBiga You need to get the MySQL server 1) running, and 2) Listening for connections from whatever machine you are using as the client.

Comment: @michael It works perfectly fine when I am connecting to it and inserting data from other functions - they all work perfectly.  I am using MySQL workbench.

Comment: @David: when you mean from other functions are you talking about within PHP or are you talking about with different mysql clients like MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Sorry Php code that uses the same MySQL db

Comment: @David: Additionally youre going about prepared statements all wrong! `$insertdata = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csvdata (firstname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$insertdata->execute(array($firstname,$lastname,$email,$phone));`

Comment: @Michael for instance, I have a members table where it check to see if user is registered in the system.  I am able to access the data and insert (if someone registers).

Comment: @Prodigitalson could you tell me more?

Comment: @prodigitalson nothing. Did not work.

Comment: @David: didnt mean that was actually going to solve the issue youre asking about... it was more general information :-)

Comment: Are you creating a new PDO object multiple times in the same script? Usually that's done once per script, before executing the function.  If you are attempting to open multiple connections in the same script, the server may be denying it for some reason.

Comment: Michael no not in same script not at all.

Comment: This script is completely separate from everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily part of your issue but you are using prepared statmemnts incorrectly. PArt of the point of using prepared statments is so that the DB takes care of the db specific escaping. In order to do this you write the query with placeholders that then get replaced with the the values passed to the statement. So in this case:

```
$insertdata = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csvdata (firstname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"); 
$insertdata->execute(array($firstname,$lastname,$email,$phone));
```

Or with named placeholders which is a bit more robust:

```
$insertdata = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csvdata (firstname, lastname, email, phone) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :phone)"); 
$insertdata->execute(array(
  ':firstname' => $firstname,
  ':lastname' => $lastname,
  ':email' => $email,
  ':phone' => $phone
));
```

Now as far as your error id be willing to bet you are using `localhost` as the hostname which can cause issues on windows - try using `127.0.0.1` instead. So for example:

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=the_db_name", $username, $password);
```

Comment: Oh thanks that helps a lot!  But ya I still have the error :/.

Comment: No I am using server from host provider.

Comment: Wait - so is this code running on the hosting server or on your local development machine? Also does the DB run on another hostname or does it run on your webserver?

Comment: Okay so win host is the host provider.  I set up a MySQL db... create username password - they give me the hostname.

Comment: Umm it doesnt seem that this answered the question. Instead of updating the question with the resolution, add your own answer and be sure to give the technical details about what you were doing wrong (since it wasnt the hostname but the insert). You can then select that as the answer after a waiting period. This way it may help others. I dont deserve anything more than an upvote at the most for my details about prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out guys thanks for all your help. I actually needed to fill in all the data columns for it to work. For instance I had (firstname,lastname,email,phone) I needed to fill in the username,password,status part. Thanks for all your help guys! Hope this will help anyone who falls in the same hole!

```
while (($fileop=fgetcsv($handle)) !== false)
{

    $fileop=array_map("trim",$fileop);

    $firstname = $fileop[$firstname_index];

    $lastname = $fileop[$lastname_index];

    $email = $fileop[$email_index];

    $phone = $fileop[$phone_index];

    $csvusername = $firstname . $lastname;

    $csvpasswordname = $lastname . $firstname;

    $status = "Open";




    $sth = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO csvdata (firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password, status, memberview) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
    $sth->execute(array($firstname, $lastname, $email, $phone, $csvusername, $csvpasswordname, $status, $memberview));

}
```