# PDO Exception in laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

I have install laravel4.2 on wamp and I am using Eloquent for insert data  to database.
I'm getting an error when open browser and type url : localhost:8000/register
PDO Exception(2002)
SQLSTATE[HY000][2002]No Connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

**RegisterController.php**

```
public function store()
{
    $validation = new RegisterValidator ;
    if($validation -> passes())
    {
        $register = new Register ;
        $register->name     = Input::get('name') ;
        $register->lname    = Input::get('lname') ;
        $register->gender   = Input::get('gender') ;
        $register->year     = Input::get('year') ;
        $register->month    = Input::get('month') ;
        $register->day      = Input::get('day') ;
        $register->username = Input::get('username') ;
        $register->password = Input::get('password') ;
        $register->mail     = Input::get('mail') ;
        $register->save() ;
        return Redirect::route('socialnetwork.register');
    }
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation->errors);

}
```

**Register.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models ;

use Eloquent;

class Register extends \Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'register' ;
}
?>
```

**app\config\database.php**

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'db_socialnetwork',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Please tell me what do i do?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523298/error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-mac or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12010524/sqlstatehy000-2002-error

Comment: Sounds like the MySQL daemon is either not running, or is not listening on TCP 127.0.0.1, and expecting a connection on a socket (localhost) instead.